# Best way to get get_defined_vars() in set_error_handler-ed function

Tags: php

I want get_defined_vars() when any error is occurred.

```php
$v = 123;  // some variable

// error handler
$f = function() {
  print_r(get_defined_vars());  // I get empty array because no variable is declared in this scope ;(
};

set_error_handler($f); // setting my handler function

1 / 0; // causing some error
```

How do I get $v in my function?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
$v = 123;  // some variable

function f($vars) {
   print_r($vars);
}   

set_error_handler(f(get_defined_vars()));

1/0;
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems ok but this get_defined_vars() is evaluated when handler is set, 
 getting global scope variables then. So, for example, if error is occurred in function, what I get is _GET, _COOKIE, ... like that, global variables. I want just local variables and args of the function. My question code is bad, sorry sir..

Comment: you can checkout this : set_error_handler(f(array_keys(get_defined_vars()))

Comment: As I mentioned, I just want local variables and args of the function, not keys.